# get count of items in two different tables into one resulting table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to obtain two different counts in a query. One count would be the count of the specific item in one table, and the other count would be the same but from a different table.  I can write 2 different queries that provides me the info but in two different tables. I would like to write one query that puts it all into one table.  Thank you guys for any of suggestions.

EDIT: To clarify, I would like to add the count from the second query to a column on the first query.

My query

```
select d.description, count(item_id) from productdetails pd
join inventory i on i.itemnum=pd.item_id
join departments d on d.dept_id=i.dept_id
where i.last_sold is not null and in_stock !=0
group by d.description

select d.description, count(itemnum) 
from inventory i
join departments d on d.dept_id=i.dept_id
where in_stock != 0 and last_sold is not null
group by d.description
```

Comment: just search about `union all`

Comment: Use `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Would that work for adding a column? I should have clarified, I did not want to combine the tables but to add the column with the appropriate data to the top query.

Comment: can't you add the count to the select?  ```select d.description, count(pd.item_id), count(i.itemnum)```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it just seems to add the same data as count(pd.item_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your queries in a sub-query where each count has been established and the "missing" count is assigned a value of zero.

Next, sum the count.

```
   SELECT smmry.description
     , SUM(smmry.pd_item_cnt) pd_item_cnt
     , SUM(smmry.itemnum_cnt) itemnum_cnt
  FROM (
        SELECT d.description
             , COUNT(pd.item_id) pd_item_cnt
             , 0 itemnum_cnt
          FROM productdetails pd
          JOIN inventory i
            ON i.itemnum =  pd.item_id
          JOIN departments d
            ON d.dept_id =  i.dept_id
         WHERE i.last_sold IS NOT NULL
           AND in_stock  != 0
         GROUP BY d.description
         UNION ALL
        SELECT d.description
             , 0 pd_item_cnt
             , COUNT(i.itemnum) itemnum_cnt
          FROM inventory i
          JOIN departments d
            ON d.dept_id =  i.dept_id
         WHERE in_stock  != 0
           AND last_sold IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY d.description
       ) smmry
 GROUP BY smmry.description
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I am trying to add the 2nd count to a 3rd column on one table, which the UNION would not satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Query1 (Description1, Count1) AS (
    select d.description, count(item_id) from productdetails pd
    join inventory i on i.itemnum=pd.item_id
    join departments d on d.dept_id=i.dept_id
    where i.last_sold is not null and in_stock !=0
    group by d.description
),
Query2 (Description2, Count2) AS (
    select d.description, count(itemnum) 
    from inventory i
    join departments d on d.dept_id=i.dept_id
    where in_stock != 0 and last_sold is not null
    group by d.description
)
SELECT Description1, Count1, Description2, Count2 FROM Query1, Query2
```